# Out of gas exception when calling contract function

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I am calling the contract function below however I get an error: "VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas". To test I have simplified the function so it only saves a user's name however I still get the error so I know it is not due to an actual out of gas reason but more due to an error. Running on Ganache.

```
function createUser(
    address _address, 
    string memory _name, 
    string memory _companyName, 
    int _numYearsExperience, 
    int _pricePerHour, 
    string memory _specialisation, 
    string memory _summary,
    int _numAdsViewed,
    int _numAdsPurchased
    ) public 

{

    address _userAddress = _address;

    // Storage for list of users
    User storage user = users[_userAddress];


    // Check that the user did not already exist
    require(
        !user.set,
        "User already exists!"
        );


    //Store the user
    users[_userAddress] = User({
        name: _name,
        companyName: _companyName,
        numYearsExperience: _numYearsExperience,
        pricePerHour: _pricePerHour,
        specialisation: _specialisation,
        summary: _summary,
        set: true,
        numAdsViewed: _numAdsViewed,
        numAdsPurchased: _numAdsPurchased
    });
}
```

This is the calling code... (JS)

```
var info = data[i]
var name = String(info.name)
var companyName = String(info.companyName)
var pricePerHour = parseInt(info.pricePerHour);
var yearsExperience = parseInt(info.yearsExperience);
var specialisation = String(info.specialisation)
var summary = String(info.summary)
var address = info.address;
var maxCPT = parseInt(info.maxCPT);

await sellContract.methods.createUser(address, name, companyName, yearsExperience, pricePerHour, specialisation, summary, 0, 0).send({ from: accounts[0]})
```

Anyone know what's going wrong??

[image: full error trace]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the gas amount in your contract call:

```
await sellContract.methods.createUser(...).send({ from: accounts[0], gas: 20000000})
```

Comment: doing that I now get "Returned error: Exceeds block gas limit"

Comment: You may need to adjust the gas number for your blockchain's limits, I just put an arbitrary number.

Comment: I did change the gas limit via: ganache-cli -p 9545 -l 90000000, however I still get the error saying I have exceeded the block gas limit

Comment: ok I just made it much higher (90000000000000) and it has solved it.. thanks

Comment: You are doing the wrong thing here. You should not need to update your blockchain's total gas limit, just the amount of gas you specify your transaction can use. I put an arbitrary number (200 million) which is probably way too much for what you need. You should try to [estimate the gas costs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethestimategas) then submit the transaction with that amount.